# Appending the DOM of the count on every pass in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, loops, load

I'll explain a little about this first but I'll try to keep it short and simple.

I have designed a map, which its information is added on load using ajax. Using a for loop, it adds six data attributes to every div where the ID matches. I'm hoping to add a loading progress function as it takes about 4 - 8 seconds to complete and this is what I'm having a problem with.

This is the full part of the code in question. You can skip if you want as I written the parts I'm having issues with underneath.

```
$.ajax({

    // Get information 
    type:'GET',
    url:'../../DataFile.php',
    data:"#roomtable table",
    success: function(data){

        //Total Count of Rooms
        totCount = $(".room").length;

        //Initalise Count
        count = 0;

        //For each room
        $('.room').each(function(){
            thisRoom = $(this);

            //Increase Count
            count++;

            //For each row in data table
            $($(data).find('tr')).each(function() {

                //If ID matched first cell
                if (thisRoom.attr('id') == $(this).find('td:nth(0)').html())
                {
                    .....
                    //Add data attributes from the other cells. 
                    .....
                }
            });

            //Write the current count as a percentage. 
            $('#count').text(Math.round(count/totCount*100));
        });
    }
});
```

The part I'm having trouble with is on every pass through the each function I was hoping the count would increase by the percentage. e.g 1/100.... 16/100... 25/100... and so. But what is happening is it just pauses until the data attributes have been written and jumps straight to 100%.

```
count = 0;
$('.room').each(function(){
    count++;
    $('#count').text(Math.round(count/totCount*100));
});
```

How come the above code doesn't write the new count on each pass? Please can someone help me where I am going wrong. I apologise the question is a little bit wordy and thanks in advance.

Comment: browsers may decide to NOT redraw the screen while doing dom manipulations in a loop as a speed-up mechanism. redrawing the screen/reflowing the document is an extremely expensive operation.

Comment: You'd have to write your code asynchronously if you want the count to display as a counter.

Comment: What is `data`, and how many `.room`s are there? It shouldn't need that long if you'd use a proper data structure to search.

Comment: @MarcB it does seem to pause the rest of the browser so that could be why.

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm pretty new to this so I haven't looked a asynchronously writing yet, but I will do now.

Comment: @Bergi It is a dynamically created html table inside a php file and it has 208 rooms... is this not the best way to do it? (it was the only way I could think of :S )

Comment: At least, parse the html table into a native JavaScript object once and use that, instead of repeatedly iterating the DOM (and using very inefficient jQuery for that).

Comment: @Bergi thanks I will take a another look about how I'm getting the data in. I'm thinking down the lines of an array of arrays.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the advice! I'm now parsing the CSV data on the client side using an array of arrays and completely skipping the html table created in the php file on the server. Now it takes less than a second to complete the whole process! No need for a loading progress anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded, when your code is busy doing some computation, UI thread has not chance to update. You may consider use `setTimeout` or something like Underscore's [defer](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#defer) function to achieve your goal. The documentation of `defer` is as follows:

> _.defer(function, [*arguments])

Defers invoking the function until the current call stack has cleared, similar to using setTimeout with a delay of 0. Useful for performing expensive computations or HTML rendering in chunks without blocking the UI thread from updating.